# How do I manually cause a 'select' event on an Openlayers 3 ol.interaction.Select?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I'd like to cause an ol.interaction.Select obj to 'select' a feature when the user clicks on a button which is related to that feature. I'd like to be able to reuse the event handling code I already use for when a user clicks on a feature.

Is there a way to do this with the Select interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- UPDATE -->
```

Maybe when this [PR](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4102) get merged we can dispatch `select` event. About reusing code, I guess you can solve this wrapping it on a function, and when push a feature to the collection, call your function with that feature.

```
<!-- End of update -->
```

Get the `ol.interaction.Select` [collection](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#getFeatures) and `push` or `pop` as you want:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    //some options
});
map.addInteraction(select);

var collection = select.getFeatures();
collection.push(some_feature);

//or push an array of features
collection.extend(some_array_features);
```

Comment: This will trigger the 'select' event? I guess I should just try it.

Comment: No trigger. Just increment collection.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Maybe it is just bad design to try to manually trigger the 'select' interaction event.  I will try to do something else.

Comment: BTW your contribution to 3.10 was great, I immediately used it. Maybe you can allow the 'layers' option in the select interaction to be a Collection next, instead of just an array? :)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice right. You want to trigger manually. I'll see if there's an option.